# Content disposition is null after applying SSL certificate, why?

Tags: c#, angularjs, azure, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-webapi

We have implemented some download functionality. We are setting content disposition on the api side. By doing this our UI will get the file name from content disposition.

This was working fine until we added a SSL certificate and moved the site to domain specific link.

Now the content disposition is coming back `null` and the file is getting downloaded with `null` as the name and no extension.

Below is our code to download the file.

```
public IActionResult DownloadFile(int ID)
{
    try
    {
        if (ValidateUsrToken())
        {
            using (ExcelPackage package = BAL.DownloadFile(ID))
            {
                string fileName = Uri.EscapeDataString(package.File.Name);

                System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                {
                    FileName = fileName,
                };

                Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

                return File(package.GetAsByteArray(), "application /vndopenxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            }
        }
        else throw new NullReferenceException();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

UI Code

```
const disposition = res.headers.get('content-disposition') || '';
if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
   const filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
   const matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
   if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
      filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
      filename = decodeURIComponent(filename);
   }
}
```

Our api & UI is implemented on azure cloud.

Any help on this appreciated.

Comment: How do you know the content disposition is coming back null?

Comment: We are checking on UI from where api is called in angular 6

Comment: It'd help if you included this code as well

Comment: @Liam Added the UI code...